# Is there a way to map a value of a response from an API in React to some predetermined values, which would then determine what is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a call to an API and its returning something similar to this:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "profile": {
            "data": {
                "userInfo": {
                    "membershipType": 4,
                    "membershipId": "4611686018483730446",
                    "displayName": "DisplayName420"
                },
            },
            "privacy": 1
        }
    },
    "ErrorCode": 1,
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0,
    "ErrorStatus": "Success",
    "Message": "Ok",
    "MessageData": {}
}
```

I want the string that is rendered to my DOM, be determined based on the value of the API's response.

For example, as the `displayName` response returns a value of `4` I want to be able to render to the DOM a string of `Battle.Net`.
Likewise if the value of `displayName` were to be `5` I'd want it to render a string of `Playstation Network`.

Is this possible? I'm using React and calling the API through a fetch function. The data returned is a JSON object.

This is my code so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Auth from './api/Auth'

class APICall extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: null,
        loading: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        var baseURL = 'https://www.bungie.net/Platform';
        var headers = {
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': '5e232bf8f19349498081bdec1d9a924b'
            }
        };

        this.setState({loading: true});
        axios.get(baseURL + '/Destiny2/4/Profile/4611686018483730446/?components=100', headers)
            .then(response => this.setState({data: response.data, loading: false}))
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        console.log(data);
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.loading
                    ? <p className={"text-white"}>"Loading..."</p>
                    :
                    <div>
                        <p className={"text-white"}>{data && data.Response.profile.data.userInfo.membershipType}</p>
                    </div>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<APICall />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<Auth />, document.getElementById('signin'));
```

Comment: Yes, just create yourself a map for the values.  Or even a simple object literal will do.

Comment: `as the displayName response returns a value of 4 I want to be able to render to the DOM a string of Battle.Net` where do you know that 4 is `Battle.Net` ? You need to provide that in your answer

Comment: @Keith could are you able to give an example of how that might work? I'm not that experienced with React or JS at the moment

Comment: @Vencovsky I haven't got those values anywhere at the moment just using them as an example, I was hoping someone could point me in the write direction and give me an example of how the values should be stored etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Simplest way is probably to have an object that's a lookup table for the various strings, and then pull out the right string based on the number. For example:

```
// somewhere, perhaps at the top of the file (outside the class)
const stringTable = {
  1: 'foo',
  2: 'bar',
  3: 'baz', 
  4: 'Battle.Net',
  5: 'Playstation Network`
}

// later, in render:
<p className={"text-white"}>{data && stringTable[data.Response.profile.data.userInfo.membershipType]}</p>
```